# Using a prior different than the uniform one

Tags: python, optimization, normal-distribution, scipy-optimize, minimization

I'm trying to find optimal parameter constraints on certain parameters using emcee library in python. The paper that I'm trying to reproduce the results from uses a gaussian prior instead of a uniform one, as given in the emcee tutorial.

Before I run MCMC, I'm using scipy.optimize to minimize the chi squared value. What I do not understand is whether or not should I take into consideration this prior now that the chi square for it isn't a constant. If yes, how to incorporate it?
Here is what I've tried:

```
def Chi_sq(parameters,H_obs1,z_obs1,sigma_obs1,D_obs,z_obs2,cov_matrix):
    #print(Chi_sq3(parameters,H_obs1,z_obs1,sigma_obs1))
    return (Chi_sq2(parameters,D_obs,z_obs2,cov_matrix)+ Chi_sq1(parameters,H_obs1,z_obs1,sigma_obs1))*np.exp(lnprior(parameters))
```

where Chi_sq1 and Chi_sq2 are my chi square statistics, and the third term that comes from
`lnprior` which is

```
def lnprior(parameters):
    omega_bh2,omega_ch2,Ho = parameters
    if not 0<=omega_bh2<=1 and 0<=omega_ch2<=1:
        return -np.inf
    mu = 68
    sigma = 2.8
    return np.log(1.0/(np.sqrt(2*np.pi)*sigma))-0.5*(Ho-mu)**2/sigma**2
```

This, however, gives wrong results. I do not know much about MCMC methods or use of a prior distribution. Any help would be appreciated.